# move_uploaded_file() upload is not working

Tags: php

My code is selecting csv file from user input. After the submission of this form. This file moves to the directory i placed in. I run this code on my machine having `windows 10` works well. When I shifted the same code on another machine having `windows XP` it is not moving file to the folder i mentioned. I have checked the permissions. It is not even displaying any error message.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $type = $_POST['sour'];
    $name       = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];  
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $location = 'Project';
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
    $newname = "newname.".$ext;
    $path = $location.$newname;

    if(!move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $path)) {
        echo "error";
    } 
    else{
        echo "success";
    }
?>
```

I am stuck. Your kind help is needed.

Comment: Does server works on xp ? yes xamp, is it runing properly ?

Comment: xampp server you are asking for?

Comment: yup it is running properly

Comment: @MariaAbdullah Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to tell us exactly what the problem is. Check with `var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);` the data you are sending from your HTML form to your PHP script.

Comment: @Progman I have edited my question. Kindly have a look

Comment: Where do you expect the file to be located after this script successfully completes? It does not look you put it inside any explicitly specified directory in this very script. Or is it really expected to have files named `Projectnewname.<ext>`?

Comment: this file will go in the htdocs of xampp and the folder name is Project. By default it takes the fath to htdocs and after that i have mentioned the folder

Comment: You don't move to a `Project` directory in this code, you rename a file to be `Projectnewname.<ext>` (it's a single file name not a path) There is no way this code to work anywhere the way you explained.

Comment: but surprisingly it works on my machine. but does not work on another pc. kindly help me with the issue

Comment: @MariaAbdullah Please [edit] your question to include the output from `var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);`.

Comment: @MariaAbdullah this very code cannot work on any machine, you presumably edited this code before posting it as a question and broken it even further.